# How to set CMake search paths

Tags: linux, cmake

In my CMakeLists.txt

```
include (CheckFunctionExists.cmake)
```

When I run `ccmake` (I am following the official [tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html))

```
 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (include):
   include could not find load file:

     CheckFunctionExists.cmake
```

However, I *have* the file specified:

```
sw3@pc90313-sw3:~/learn_cmake/build$ find / -name CheckFunctionExists.cmake 2>/dev/null
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.cmake
```

I am using a cmake installation form the Ubuntu 13.04 repository:

```
sw3@pc90313-sw3:~/learn_cmake/build$ cmake --version
cmake version 2.8.10.1
```

---

If the absolute path is specified, everything works out well and a working makefile is generated. However, this workaround is far from ideal (and diverges from the tutorial). Where could the problem be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The path is called `${CMAKE_ROOT}`. So the proper include command for system files is

```
include (${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.cmake)
```

, mentioned later in the tutorial.